# django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: ['“F(version) + Value(1)” value must be an integer.'] while using reversions

Tags: django, django-reversion

I am trying to use reversions to get keep the revisions of my model, but my model has a field that is updated like this `self.version = F("version") + 1`.
Now if I use the below code, I am getting this error `django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: ['“F(version) + Value(1)” value must be an integer.']`

```
        with transaction.atomic(), reversion.create_revision():
            self.save()
            reversion.set_user(user)
```

but if I use this code, the revision is working fine, but I think this is quite inefficient, is there any other way to do this??

```
        self.save()
        with transaction.atomic(), reversion.create_revision():
            self.refresh_from_db()
            self.save()
            reversion.set_user(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of `django-reversion`!

Using `F` is not supported by `django-reversion`, and probably can't be. However, you can get a similar effect with reasonable efficiency like this:

```
with transaction.atomic(), reversion.create_revision():
    MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get(id=self.id)
    self.version = self.version + 1
    self.save()
```

The `select_for_update()` ensures the version update is atomic while retaining compatibility with `django-reversion`.

Comment: No problem! Please mark the answer as accepted if you're happy, and feel free to post an issue on the django-reversion repo for a more in-depth discussion.